# To Show a Certain Martingale has Bounded Difference Property

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space and $(\Omega_i, \mathcal F_i)$ be measurable spaces for $i=1, \ldots, m$.
Let $Z_i:\Omega\to \Omega_i$ be a measurable function for each $i$, and let $Z:\Omega\to \Omega_1\times \cdots\times \Omega_m$ be defined as $Z=(Z_1, \ldots, Z_m)$.
Assume that $Z_1, \ldots, Z_m$ are independent.

Let $f:\Omega_1\times \cdots\times \Omega_m\to \mathbf R$ be Borel measurable with the property that
$$|f(\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_m)-f(\omega_1', \ldots, \omega_m')|<C$$
whenever $(\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_m)$ and $(\omega_1', \ldots, \omega_m')$ differ in only one coordinate.

For each $i=1, \ldots, m$, define $S_i:\Omega\to \mathbf R$ as
$$S_i=E(f\circ Z|\ Z_1, \ldots Z_i)$$
It is clear that $S_1, \ldots, S_m$ forms a martingale on $\Omega$.

> I want to show that $|S_{i+i}-S_i|\leq C$ for each $i\geq 1$.

This is easy to show when each $Z_i$ has finite image. For then $S_i$ is constant on each part of the common refinement of the partitions of $\Omega$ formed by the fibres of $Z_1, \ldots, Z_i$. But I fail to see how to do this in general.

---

What I tried doing is:

Let's try to show $|S_2-S_1|\leq C$.
But $$S_1=E(F\circ Z|\ Z_1) = E(E(f\circ Z|\ Z_1)|\ Z_1, Z_2)$$
Thus $$S_2-S_1 = E(f\circ Z|\ Z_1, Z_2) - E(E(f\circ Z|\ Z_1)|\ Z_1, Z_2)$$
which gives
$$S_2-S_1 = E(f\circ Z - E(f\circ Z|\ Z_1)|\ Z_1, Z_2)$$
but I am getting nowhere from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becasue the $Z_i$ are independent, $S_1=E(f(Z)|Z_1)=h_1(Z_1)$, where
$$
h_1(x):=E(f(x,Z_2,\ldots,Z_m)).
$$
Likewise,
$S_2=h_2(Z_1,Z_2)$, where
$$
h_2(x,y) :=E(f(x,y,Z_3,\ldots,Z_m)).
$$
So 
$S_2-S_1=g(Z_1,Z_2)$, where
$$
g(x,y) =E\left[f(x,Z_2,Z_3,\ldots,Z_m)-f(x,y,Z_3,\ldots,Z_m)\right].
$$
The claim follows because $|f(x,Z_2,Z_3,\ldots,Z_m)-f(x,y,Z_3,\ldots,Z_m)|\le C$ by the hypothesis on $f$. The inequalities for $i=2,3,\ldots,m-1$ follow in the same way.